# How to make a PHP function into a short code

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to turn the following line of PHP into a shortcode in my functions.php so that I can add it to a Wordpress page.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); ?>
```

After some research I found the code below for creating shortcodes, but I'm not sure how to add the line of PHP above to it to it, or even if it is the correct way to do this.

```
function menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null){
    return '<nav class="main-menu-header">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</nav>';
}

add_shortcode('nav', 'menu_shortcode');
```

I initially assumed I was to add the code between the brackets of `do_shortcode` instead of having `$content`, but this gave me an error.

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `do_shortcode` is to perform a search for shortcodes in the input parameter, and execute those short codes. You need that if you have nested shortcodes - but for a menu, there’s likely no content that needs further shortcode expansion. You want your shortcode to return the menu, so you have to call `wp_nav_menu` somewhere in your function.

Comment: That's gone over my head a bit I'm afraid, I'm very inexperienced with PHP. I had a go at trying to find a solution but I've obviously overcomplicated things and have been looking for answers in the wrong places. I basically just need the shortcode to display the menu links that I've configured in the appearance section within Wordpress. If I add the following PHP – `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); ?>` to my html in my header.php template, it works. Is there any way I can also get this to show up on my Wordpress pages without resorting to using a plugin?

Comment: And @Scriptman, I didn't actually upload it to my site in the end, I just got the red error warnings in dreamweaver when I pasted the code in. I knew it was a bit of a stab in the dark but thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what i understand from your above question this will work for you. Add it to your **functions.php** and then use **[nav]** to display it.

```
function menu_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header', 'echo' => false ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'nav', 'menu_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thanks, this may seem like a silly question, but which part is the actual shortcode – i.e which part do I type in to activate the function?

Comment: As i said above write the above function in functions.php and then write [nav] in the wordpress page where you want to show it.

Comment: Don't forget to set the echo arg to false otherwise it won't work in a shortcode context

Comment: Good point @NathanDawson I have edited my answer. I just focused on answering the exact question and forgot about this.

Comment: To be specific the first parameter of add_shortcode is the actual shortcode and the second is name of the function it runs.