# Custom shortcode always displays at top of page

Tags: php, wordpress

I realise there are similar questions to this on here, but all contain slightly different code to mine. I have a custom shortcode configured in the `functions.php` file, and for some reason it always displays at the top of the page. Nothing I do seems to be able to move it. Is this a result of something in the code?

```
function menu_shortcode( $atts ) {
     return wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'nav', 'menu_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I think nav is already used by wordpress, try changing it to something more unique.

Comment: This didn't make a difference I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shortcode is returning `wp_nav_menu()` but that function will output by default. Shortcodes aren't allowed to generate output so you need to set echo to false to prevent it.

```
function menu_shortcode( $atts ) {
     return wp_nav_menu( array( 
         'theme_location' => 'header',
         'echo' => false, 
     ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'nav', 'menu_shortcode' );
```

Documentation:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

*The answer you received to your original question has been updated to fix the problem you've described: [How to make a PHP function into a short code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760208/how-to-make-a-php-function-into-a-short-code)*

Answer (score 1):

All right, I've tested it on my own WordPress install with the following code:

```
function menu_shortcode() {
     return wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'b3_add_menu', 'menu_shortcode' );
```

I created a page called test and added the shortcode [b3_add_menu] to it. This is the result:

[image: Test]

For me the menu is not displayed only at the top of the page, could you maybe tell me where you placed your "nav" shortcode?

Comment: I'm using a text/code module in the page builder plugin to add the shortcode. I have also tried using the default Wordpress page editor and the other content is still pushed below that which is generated by the shortcode.